# how to connect form values in jsp to controller in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. i want to attach a model bean to a form which binds values and pass it to controller. so i did the following way

in jsp

```
<form:form modelattribute="model">
<form:input path="var1"/>
</form:form>
```

in controller

```
pulic void method(@modelattribute("model")Bean bean)
{

//my code
}
```

but when am accessing the form it throwing error as exception while rendering jsp, no such bean exists with name model

how to solve this? help me

Comment: You need to explain it better.

Comment: @VaibhavRaj i have a form in which user enter values. the values should be send to controller from form. so i followed the above process and am getting the error saying that no such bean exists with name "model". here Bean is a class which contains the variables that match the fields in the jsp page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your model class looks like:

```
public class MyModel{
    private String propOne;
    private String porpTwo;

    /*Skipping getters and setters*/
}
```

Use *@ModelAttribute* to map the user inputs to your form bean:

```
@RequestParam("/myPage")
public String myController(@ModelAttribute MyModel myModel){
    /*Do your processing here*/
}
```

On *jsp* page, just give your input fields same **name** (Html attribute: name) as the properties inside the bean to be mapped:

```
<form:input name="propOne" class="xyz" />
<form:input name="propTwo" class="xyz" />
```

Doing this much completes your bean mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save model before render the page.

```
uiModel.addAttribute("model", new Bean());
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC you will be better off using the @ModelAttribute annotation on a method in your controller which supplies your model. This will be called and automatically added to the model before your JSP is rendered.

Something like this

```
@ModelAttribute
public Model model(){
  return new Model();
}
```

I suggest you have a good read of the Spring MVC [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: cant i do this with out writing the above snippet. I mean through xml files.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the form instance to your model during the GET request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handler(final Model uiModel)
        uiModel.addAttribute("model", new Bean());
```

//do something and return a view path, probably 
    }

and in the handler method to process POST request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handler(final Bean form)
        // process your form bean here and return a view path, probably
}
```

Documentation is available here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look on Vaibhav method, I have edited it and now its working fine

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: @RadimKöhler: I am new user so I require 50 reputation to add comment to Vaibhav's answer and I have edited that post but it requires peer review then it will be available to public. Here is what I have done, I have changed the jsp tag <input name="propOne"/>
<input name="propTwo" />